# SQL Server 2008 Connection issue through ADO

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server 2008 instance in a different machine in my same domain, through C++ and ADO. I am able to connect successfully through the SQL Server Management Studio. But by passing the same credentials, in my C++ program, I am getting error: "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MyUserID'." Here is the code that I was trying with:

```
HRESULT hr = -1;
CoInitialize(NULL);
try
{
    _ConnectionPtr pConn1("ADODB.Connection");
    _CommandPtr pCmd1("ADODB.Command");
    hr = pConn1.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
    pConn1->Provider = "sqloledb";
    hr = pConn1->Open("Data Source='DATAXXX';Initial Catalog='DATA123';Integrated Security=SSPI", "XX", "xyz123", adConnectUnspecified);
    //hr value returned is : S_OK

}
catch (_com_error& ex)  //ex value is: DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED Authentication failed
{
    CString err = ex.Description();
    AfxMessageBox(err); //err = Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\\MyUserID'
}

    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("ERROR: Opening Database connection");
        return;
    }
    pCmd1->ActiveConnection = pConn1;
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. My OS is Windows 8, and I am using VS2013

Comment: when connecting from management studio , did you connect from the remote machine or same machine where sql server exists

Comment: no, when connecting to the server instance in the another machine in the network, I successfully connected the management studio from my own machine, from where I am unable to connect through my C++ program

Comment: I noticed you mentioned passing credentials , but "Integrated Security=SSPI " in connection string doesn't require developer to pass credentials , if you managed to login using a username and password , you should remove this attribute from connection string and instead add the "User ID" and "Password"

Comment: Many Thanks @Maha Khairy, removing "Integrated Security=SSPI " worked for me.